# buscar todos os registros de uma coluna sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragment

Preciso salvar em uma lista os nomes da tabela usuarios e salva-los em um ArrayList. Fiz da seguinte forma:

```
 public List<String> buscarUsuarios() {
    List<String> nomes = new ArrayList<String>();
    String selectQuery = "select nome from usuarios";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);


    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do {

            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String nomeString = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("nome"));

            StringBuilder conversor = new StringBuilder();
            conversor.append(nomeString);

            nomes.add(conversor.toString());

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());

    }
    return nomes;
}
```

Mas está dando looping infinito
Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Você está sempre movendo para o primeiro, em todos os loops. Assim, ele nunca vai chegar no fim

Comment: NOSSA é a falta de café. MUITO OBRIGADO!

Comment: embora remover funcione, o melhor seria voce posicionar ele fora do _loop_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está movendo o cursor para o primeiro registro toda a vez.

Remove o `cursor.moveToFirst();` de dentro do `do`